# Connecting HDMI device to USB 3.1 converter

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, xrandr

xrandr shows my main monitor and

```
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I have tried rebooting with cables plugged and screen device on. It says NO SIGNAL.

How do I make Ubuntu listen to USB 3.1 Thunderbolt ports and find attached devices? In the non-FOSS OSes, this is plug and play.

17.04 XPS 9350

Comment: Please [edit] and post your Ubuntu release/version and your hardware specs, namely graphics and proprietary drivers version if applicable.

Comment: When you connect a USB Type C to HDMI adapter in it will show up as "DP-1-1". Do you have a link to the adpater you bought?